# Java - ResultSet errors, How to structure it properly?

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, resultset

### EDIT - This question arised from a bug found on Eclipse, while using debug mode. The code presented in this question was not my initial attempt and everything is now solved - as long as I don't run that method in debug mode.

I'm now developing on a project that wasn't mine and I'm new to java and especially prepared statements and result sets. The reason I'm using prepared statements is because it is often used in this project and I figured I'd do the same.

My goal is to extract the only record that the query "sql" gives.
However, since this query only gives one record or none I'm struggling to code this in a way that doesn't result in "exhaust" errors or other sqlexceptions. The only exception allowed is if the query gives zero or more than 1 results, because it really shouldn't.

This is the implemented code:

```
private long getOriginalValue() throws EProjectException {
    long value = 0;


    PreparedStatement psValue = null;
    java.sql.Connection connection;
    ResultSet rsValue = null;

    String sql = "SELECT value FROM value_table WHERE value ='" + name + "'";

    try {           

        connection = (Connection) eContext.getConnection(EContext.DB_CONNECTION, "edinforsys");
        psValue = connection.prepareStatement(sql,ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,
                ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE,
                ResultSet.HOLD_CURSORS_OVER_COMMIT);

        rsValue = psValue.executeQuery();

        try {
            rsValue.beforeFirst();
            value = rsValue.getLong(1);
            if(rsValue.next())
                System.out.println("Duplicate Value");
        } catch (Exception ex){
            throw new EProjectException(UBSCMMessage.GENERAL_ERROR, ex.getMessage());
        } finally {
            rsValue.close();
        }           

        if(value == 0)
            throw new EProjectException(UBSCMMessage.GENERAL_ERROR);



    } catch (Exception ex) {
        throw new EProjectException(UBSCMMessage.GENERAL_ERROR, ex.getMessage());
    } finally {
        try {
            psValue.close();

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }           
    }       

    return value;
}
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: share exception log also

Comment: Calling `rsValue.beforeFirst();` means you need to call `rsValue.next()` before calling `getLong(1)`.

Comment: Learn about prepared statements. The whole point of using them is to be able to pass parameters, safely, to the query. But you're using string concatenation instead, defeating the whole purpose.

Comment: I've found the bug. I've been at this multiple times using the proper structure and changing it all around for nothing. The bug is actually in Eclipse. When using debug mode and using F6 to go through every step in the method the code fails, however, when using F7 or F8 to skip the method the code works. It's an Eclipse problem that I wasn't getting. The code is now: while (rsValue.next()) {value = rsValue.getLong(1);} and it works fine without debugging. However if I debug the method the while loop is skipped.

Answer (score 0):

The `getLong` was done too early, after every `next()` you have loaded the next record.

As there are some pieces that function better, here corrected code:

```
String sql = "SELECT value FROM value_table WHERE value = ?";
try {           
    connection = (Connection) eContext.getConnection(EContext.DB_CONNECTION, "edinforsys");
    try (PreparedStatement psValue = connection.prepareStatement(sql,
            ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,
            ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE,
            ResultSet.HOLD_CURSORS_OVER_COMMIT)) {

        psValue.setString(1, name); // Escapes single quotes and such
        try (ResultSet rsValue = psValue.executeQuery()) {
            //rsValue.beforeFirst();
            if (rsValue.next()) {
                long value = rsValue.getLong(1);
                System.out.println("Duplicate Value");
                return value; or whatever
            }
        } // Closes rsValue
    } // Closes psValue
} catch (SQLException ex){
    throw new EProjectException(UBSCMMessage.GENERAL_ERROR, ex.getMessage(), ex);
    // Better add the entire ex as cause if possible
}
```

A PreparedStatement where the JDBC SQL driver fills in the parameters is important. It not only escapes names like `"Marie d'Alembert"` (single quote) but also is a means against hacking, SQL injection. Of course then sql must not be a string concatenation with variables.

The try-with-resources (as of Java 7) ensures automatic closing even in case of exceptions and a return.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the loop to while loop, like the following

```
int counter=0;
while(rsValue.next()) {
   counter++;
    value= rsValue.getLong(1);
if(counter>1)
{
throw new Exception("your Exception");
}
}
//your code continues here
```

basically when we get the result set this  points before the first row, so so this rsValue.next() is required, before you can retrieve data from this.

as explained in the documentation .next will return false if there are no rows in the ResultSet.

Comment: the problem I was having was that using that sort of loop skipped the first row entirely, which was the only row so nothing was being executed. I'll try again though